# Php, I want to add a parameter for redirections in ALL links, how to do that?

Tags: php, header, location

Lets imagine a "language" parameter in every GET request. I must add this parameter to all request. Its OK to just type it in php code, but if I have thousands "header()" calls, what to do? Not mentioned the HTML/Javascript links. Sessions not an option, sorry

Comment: I would use HTTP request rewrite rules, changing the HTTP server configuration (Apache, Nginx, Lighttpd), not PHP.

Answer (score 1):

How is this different from any other get parameter?   If you require it, then your code needs to pass the value around, just as it must pass around any other get parameters that need to be retained and added to other links or Location: headers. If this represents a major logistical issue for you, you might consider the design of your controller system, and overall framework for dealing with requests and url parameters.

Comment: yea, thats right but cant it be automatic somehow? To "hook" the redirection methods so that even links from HTML/Javascript would be OK?